# Get HTML element by attribute

Tags: html, autoit

I'm using AutoIt to parse HTML. I want to get all HTML elements by an attribute's value. Example:

```
<div data-source="xxx">The div content XXX</div>
<div data-source="zzz">The div content of ZZZ</div>
```

The div -element containing the attribute-value pair `data-source="xxx"` should be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this?

```
$ohtml = ObjCreate('HTMLFILE')
$ohtml.body.innerHTML = '<div data-source="xxx">The div content XXX</div>' & @CRLF & _
                        '<div data-source="zzz">The div content of ZZZ</div>'    

Dim $selected_node
For $div in $ohtml.body.getElementsByTagName("div")
    If $div.getAttribute("data-source") = 'xxx' Then
        $selected_node = $div
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
Next

ConsoleWrite($selected_node.innerHTML & @CRLF)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that using RegExp :

```autoit
#include <Array.au3>
$Data = '<div data-source="xxx">The div content XXX</div>' & @CRLF & _
'<div data-source="zzz">The div content XXX</div>'
MsgBox ("","",$Data)
Local $array = StringRegExp($Data,"(\s.*=\x22\w.*\x22)",3)
_ArrayDisplay($array)
For $i=0 to Ubound($array)
    MsgBox ("","", $array[$i])
Next
```

And here is another example show you how to read the file.html contents and show you the extracted data :

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <FileConstants.au3>
Local Const $sFilePath = "Example.html"
; Open the file for reading and store the handle in a variable.
Local $hFileOpen = FileOpen($sFilePath, $FO_READ)
; Reads the contents of the file using the handle returned by FileOpen.
Local $sFileRead = FileRead($hFileOpen)
; Closes the handle returned by FileOpen.
FileClose($hFileOpen)
$Data = $sFileRead
Local $array = StringRegExp($Data, "(\s.*=\x22\w.*\x22)", 3)
_ArrayDisplay($array)
For $i = 0 To UBound($array)
    MsgBox("", "", $array[$i])
Next
```